# what size 2 by lumber should I use to support a swing?

Tags: wood, outdoor, lumber, swing

I want to hang a swing in my yard and none of the trees have a suitable branch. I want to run a doubled up PT 2x8 between 2 trees spanning just shy of 10 feet. Will this be strong enough? Should I upsize to 2x10? Or is there another option?  Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to see a few pictures of the trees.

Comment: Indeed - I think the big factor here will be how sturdy the trees themselves are. If they flex themselves in wind, etc, the load on the beam will be much greater.

This older post may be relevant here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8112/how-much-load-can-a-wood-board-support-if-it-is-supported-only-at-the-ends?rq=1

Comment: If it is kids at 100 or less you won't bow with doubles 2x10s.   That doesn't mean they will be sturdy and not shake or have some other issue.   Also most swings are held by hooks.   I wouldn't put a swing hook into a 2x.

Comment: it will be attached to 2 tall sturdy trees.