# Punching bag mounted on ceiling in flat

Tags: ceiling, mounting

I would like to mount a punching bag on the ceiling as there are not really any good boxing gyms here in Madrid.

Key Facts

- I am on the Ground Floor known as "Bajo" in Spanish
- The weight on the boxing bag is 70LB
- Here is the link "[Link to all the images](http://i3tek.com/bag/)" of the first and second ceiling. I can take more on request.

You can see in the images all the ceilings and the metal mount.

Comment: See also: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9176/how-to-mount-hooks-into-concrete-ceiling-that-must-be-able-to-support-several-ti

Comment: @BMitch - Hi, from what you have seen in the pictures, do you think this is possible?

Comment: If it's possible, you'd have some work to distribute the load across the ceiling, spanning multiple joists. But you didn't describe the structure and materials of the ceiling.

Comment: @BMitch - To be honey, I am not sure, this is why I included the pictures. Is there anything I can do to obtain this information or any key things I am looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If photos 6/7 are indicating you have some kind of dropped ceiling, then you definitely cannot attach this to the dropped ceiling. It won't support any load.

Best option in that case is to build a free standing structure and hang your bag on that. A couple of A frames and a beam going across the top where you'd attach the bag would be easy to build. Use a few bolts for the assembly and it would also be easy to disassemble and relocate. Keep the span of the feet wider than the maximum swing of the bag to avoid having it tip over.

Comment: Free standing structure is the way to go, neighbors might not like it if the bag is attached to their floor.

Comment: @BMitch - The first ceiling is a false one however the second  one is a lot more stronger. I hung 140KG from that metal pole in picture 011 me + punching bag, but of course. vibration is a BIG thing to consider. However in picture 009 there is a metal and concrete beam, I think. A standalone solution is not viable. The pictures are just to show what I have. I can make a video is needed. Thanks

Comment: Any other solution?

Comment: @Arthor None from me. The ceiling doesn't look all that strong, so if you can't do a free standing solution, there may not be any solution.

Comment: @BMitch - Hi.. Ok, maybe this will help. I can confirm that image 009 is a metal beam. Could I used this?

Comment: @Arthor - If I said yes, you should immediately ignore any advice I gave you since I can't tell what that beam is connected to, what condition the beam is in, what it's supporting, etc. This can't be diagnosed over the internet, you need someone physically there with structural engineering experience. That said, the beam should be supporting the floor above it, so if it happens to fail because you used it for something it wasn't designed for, then be ready for some very upset neighbors.

Comment: @Bmitch - yes you are correct. There is in fact. 4 floors above me. I will investigate more and see if I can get a pen camera up there. Who would of though that a 70Lb bag would be so difficult! :)